# Extracting the time between two-time value from excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I encountered a blockage in extracting the time between two-time values from excel. Below are some examples.

Can someone help me?

```
Start date                         End date
12/31/2019, 09:44 AM           01/06/2020, 05:04 PM
01/06/2020, 07:37 AM           01/06/2020, 04:37 PM
01/06/2020, 08:28 AM           01/06/2020, 05:07 PM
01/07/2020, 07:45 AM           01/07/2020, 08:30 AM
01/07/2020, 08:30 AM           01/07/2020, 04:55 PM
01/07/2020, 09:43 AM           01/07/2020, 04:34 PM
01/08/2020, 07:48 AM           01/08/2020, 11:35 AM
01/09/2020, 08:31 AM           01/09/2020, 05:21 PM
```

Thank you!
Cotiso

Comment: What's the nature of the roadblock? What have you tried, and what was the result? Have you tried subtraction?

Comment: You should also indicate the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If the start times are in column A, beginning in A2, and the ending times are in column B, beginning in A2, then the following formula would parse the text in each column then use `TIMEVALUE()` and `DATEVALUE` on each piece to get the starting and ending day/time values as Excel sees them. Subtracting the starting pair from the addition of the ending pair gives the elapsed time.

It's decimal as is. So, say `6.305555556`. The formula actually takes that and makes it a text string that is formatted to show it as `days, hours, minutes`:

```
=LET(  ElapsedTime,  DATEVALUE(LEFT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1))  +
    TIMEVALUE(MID(B2,FIND(",",B2)+2,LEN(B2)))  -  
    DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1))  -
    TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,LEN(A2))),

    TEXT(  INT(ElapsedTime),  "@")  &  " days, "  &
    TEXT(  (ElapsedTime-INT(ElapsedTime)),  "H \h\o\u\r\s\,\ M \m\i\n\u\t\e\s"))
```

`ElapsedTime` is the portion described above. The last portion is simply the required formatting to achieve an elapsed time in "Days, Hours, and Minutes"

So acting on the first pair, the output would be `6 days, 7 hours, 20 minutes` formatted, and `6.305555556` days for the unformatted version.

The unformatted version is a true number while the formatted version is simply text. Each has its merits. If one desires a true number, but the formatted appearance, use just the ElapsedTime portion and format it with this (below everything) number format:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1))  +
 TIMEVALUE(MID(B2,FIND(",",B2)+2,LEN(B2)))  -  
 DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1))  -
 TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,LEN(A2)))


D "days, "H "hours ", M "minutes"
```

After all, the needs you could have could vary a lot. Maybe it's for payroll (decimal preferred, no doubt), for no further use as a true number and wanting to cement that in place by conversion to a formatted text string that still nicely conveys the information, or the in-between formatted true number.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

*This will extract the time between two Date-Time value.*

**:Caveat:**

*You are working with wrong Date Time format `12/31/2019, 09:44 AM`, since COMMA separates Date & Time, and cell format is `General`, which produce #VALUE! error, if formula applied.*

[image]

- Formula in cell AR2:

  ```
  =IF(AP2>AO2,INT(AP2-AO2)&" days "&TEXT(AP2-AO2,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """),MOD(AP2-AO2,1))
  ```

**N.B.**

- Cell format on Column AO & AP are, `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM`, and column AR has `General`.
- The prime reason behind using this formula is that, you have DATE TIME value rather than only TIME value, and in this situation 24 Hrs time calculation is required, cozz there should be value for two different dates, as you have in AO2 & AP2.
- Otherwise you may simply use `=AP2-AO2`, to get difference in Hours, which is wrong in case as you have values in AO2 & AP2 cells.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hello, Rajesh
I have this information downloaded from an application.
The setting mode is not in my control.
I need to convert the information in these cells to process and find out how many days, hours, and minutes have passed since the final day and the start day. If I remove the comma, the format of the information does not change in all cells in excel
Thx

Comment: @LascuCotiso ,,,, check the screen shot, I've removed the COMMA, otherwise you get #VALUE! error,, if U have bulk data better use Find & Replace!!

Comment: @ Rajesh S - Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help U @LascuCotiso ,,, if you feel then you may Up vote as well as accept my post & answer ,, and keep asking ☺